# Removing Facebook application through API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a web app that adds an application to a users profile, and requests extended permissions.

I can't seem to find if there is a way to use a script to remove the application from the users profile when they request to do so from my web app. I know they can remove the app when logged into Facebook, but I want to know if I can remove the app with an API call. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED: As others have mentioned, Facebook now has this API. I don't think there is a way to change the accepted answer to give credit unfortunately.

From: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/permissions/#Deleting

> You can revoke a specific permission by making a call to a Graph API
>   endpoint:
>
> DELETE /{user-id}/permissions/{permission-name}
>
> This request must be made with a user access token or an app access
>   token for the current app. If the request is successful, you will
>   receive a response of true.

Note that excluding {permission-name} will revoke all permissions.

Comment: Great, that's what I needed. I couldn't find anything on it, so I guess I needed another confirmation.

Comment: This is no longer true. See newer answers below, using the DELETE method on the /{user-id}/permissions path.

Comment: It's in the API at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.4#revokelogin

Answer (score 16):

You can use a HTTP DELETE request with:

From http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#permissions:

You can de-authorize an application or revoke a specific extended permissions on behalf of a user by issuing an HTTP DELETE request to PROFILE_ID/permissions with a user access_token for that app.

Answer (score 11):

The accepted answer is over 3 years old and is now outdated.

From: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/permissions/#Deleting

> You can revoke a specific permission by making a call to a Graph API endpoint:
>
> `DELETE /{user-id}/permissions/{permission-name}`
>
> This request must be made with a user access token or an app access token for the current app. If the request is successful, you will receive a response of `true`.

Note that excluding `{permission-name}` will revoke all permissions.

Answer (score 3):

This is the javascript way (Fb js sdk api call) to remove the application from the user profile:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7741978/246435

Answer (score 0):

I have a PHP example if anyone is interested (with Graph v5 in 2017):

```
# v5 with default access token fallback
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([/* . . . */]);

$fb->setDefaultAccessToken('{access-token}');

# These will fall back to the default access token
$response = $fb->get('/me');
$response = $fb->post('/me/feed', $data);
$response = $fb->delete('/123', $data);
```

So you would have to use:

```
$response = $fb->delete('/123', $data);
```

Instead of using the `FacebookRequest` class in v4.