# Remove the application from a user using graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am developing a facebook application, I want to remove my application from a user using Graph API, is there any way to do this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook API SDK revoke access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050190/facebook-api-sdk-revoke-access)

Answer (score 25):

When the user is connected, do:

```
FB.api("/me/permissions","DELETE",function(response){
    console.log(response); //gives true on app delete success 
});
```

Comment: I keep getting "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user" returned, despite being connected still... EDIT: nevermind, it was an issue with getLoginStatus() having not returned yet, once I ran it again it worked.

Comment: Or do a backend call. Graph API doc: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.4#revokelogin

Answer (score 1):

I got this working with a serverside request using [Using ASP.Net with Facebook’s Graph API and OAuth 2.0 Authentication](http://osnapz.wordpress.com/2010/04/23/using-asp-net-with-facebooks-graph-api-and-oauth-2-0-authentication/) this article as reference you get a auth token then when they redirect back to your callback you post a delete request to the graph url e.g.

"https://graph.facebook.com/person_id/permissions?access_token=token