# Facebook registration plugin: Registration lifecycle management (unregister)

Tags: facebook, registration

Folks,

I want to use facebook's registration plugin to register users on my site. During development I will be registering an unregistering from my site several times. What is the way for my site to convey an un-register even to facebook?

I need this because when a user who is already registered with my site visits my site's registration page, the Facebook-rendered iframe says that the user is already registered.

This goes to a more general question about registration lifecycle management. Hope to get some pointers.

Thanks.

Comment: That's how it should be working , isn't it ? ;) If you want to give options for unregister, then you should give a link within your site where users can unregister themselves. And you can remove the users from your database if you store them.. :)

Comment: Hi Vijay, Thanks for the comment. To improve user workflow, I would like my site to unregister the user from my site's Facebook app and remove their info from my site's DB in one shot. I would like to programmatically delete my app from the user's profile on unregister. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this link ,

[Remove the application from a user using graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6634212/remove-the-application-from-a-user-using-graph-api)

I tried the solution given by Qlimax,

I tried removing one of my sample application permissions and then visited my apps tab and i couldn't see that application..

But i'm not sure whether that would have removed the whole application or would have left any traces by removing only the permission i gave for that application..

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the app from account settings in facebook.  this will unregister the user from the facebook side.