# How to delete/clear facebook access token or make it expired in webview?

Tags: facebook, xamarin, facebook-login, access-token

I'm trying to implemente a login and logout function using facebook following the documentation here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow#checklogin
the login works fine, but when I want to log out, I didn't find a way to manully make the access_token expired/deleted.
I have tried 
[Remove the application from a user using graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6634212/remove-the-application-from-a-user-using-graph-api) 
but it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why doesn't deleting the token work? Do you get an exception? Also, what is your code for logging out? It is difficult to help you without any code to look at

Comment: Did you try clearing the Cookies using the CookieManager?