# How to remove a user from my facebook-app?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

There are plenty of threads out there discussing "how can a user remove permission for an app". I would like to know the opposite: How can I remove a user who is connected to my app? The user pressed the facebook login-button before. And I have a "delete my account" function but some users who are not in the database anymore are still connected to my app. I would like to remove the connection! Thx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can´t, because it is completely up to the user.

You can only remove permissions with a User Token in your "delete my account" function, there is a lot of information about that in another thread: [Removing Facebook application through API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037841/removing-facebook-application-through-api)

...or specifically in this article in the FB docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/permissions/#Deleting